# How to accommodate APIView & ViewSet views in urls.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-urls

How would one write a urls.py file to accommodate views created from APIView and ViewSet.

**entity.views.py**

```
from .models import Entity
from .serializers import EntitySerializer

class EntityViewSet(DefaultsMixin, ListCreateRetrieveUpdateViewSet):
    """
    """
    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntitySerializer
    filter_fields = ('id', 'entity_number')

class PersonProfileList(APIView):
    """
    person profile
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pass
```

**entity.urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from . import views

entity_router = DefaultRouter()
entity_router.register(r'entity', views.EntityViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'profile/$', views.PersonProfileList.as_view(), name='profile_list'),  # Is this correct?
    url(r'profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PersonProfileList.as_view(), name='profile_detail'),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**main urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from entities.urls import entity_router, urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^entities/', include(entity_router.urls)),  #This I know works
    url(r'^entities/', include(urlpatterns.url)),  # This throws errors
]
```

What is the best way to accommodate both types of Views in the same URL file and have them appear under one `/entity` unlike now when am getting two /entity entries. Also, once I get into the /entity page in the browsable API, how do I make the `/entity/profile` viewable since now it only shows `/entity`. See images for guide.

**Root Page**
[image: Root URL Page]

**Entities Page**
[image: Entities URL Page]